# System::String to char* and back in C++/CLI: Faster than Marshal?

Tags: string, c++-cli, char

In a C++/CLI project (Visual Studio 2010), what is the best way to convert a System::String to a char* so it can be sent to a system function, and similarly convert the received char* to System::String?

Is there a faster way than using the System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char*` or `wchar_t*`? `const` or no? If what you really need is a `const wchar_t*` you can do it pretty quick with [`PtrToStringChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/585whdf9(VS.80).aspx)  from vcclr.h which won't incur any copying overheard (you'll need to pin the result still however).

Going the other way you're probably not going to be able to significantly beat `Marshal`, `System::String` does have constructors that take pointers though.

Comment: It's just a char*.  If I pin the string, won't that adversely affect the memory management?

Comment: Yes, but you need to pin it for the duration of the system function or else the GC could move it out from under you. If it's a `char*` you'll have to do some copying anyway then.

Comment: Just for reference, can I unpin it?  Does it come unpinned after execution leaves the context of the pinning pointer?

Comment: Right if you use `pin_ptr` it's RAIIed. When the `pin_ptr` goes out of scope it gets unpinned.

Comment: I'm sending it to a function that expects char*.  Can I use wchar_t* and cast it to char* without copying?

Comment: No. That would cause undefined behavior. You need to convert the unicode string into a real char* (unless this function operates on the data as a bag of bytes and doesn't treat it as an actual string). What's the function (if it would be useful to share)?

Comment: It's a filename.  QTMLGetCanonicalPathName(char*, char*, unsigned long) - part of the QuickTime SDK for Windows.  Thanks for the help!